# Having difficulty with MySQL based web site using table join

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database in which are two tables which represent the same data but from different sources (so the structure is the same but individual data points might be different)

Complicating things in my code is that in two of the tables, they have the same column title (M_A)

Here is the code on my index.php page:

```
<?php
include ("includes.php");
$nvPosts = GetNVPosts();
include ("displaynvtable.php");
?>
```

Here is the relevant part of my includes.php:

```
function GetNVPosts ($inID=null)
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT table1.id, table1.county, table1.M_A, table2.M_A FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.county = table2.county");
$postArray = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $myPost = new NVPost($row["id"], $row['county'], $row['M_A'], $row['M_A']);
            array_push($postArray, $myPost);
}
return $postArray;
echo $postArray;
}
```

Here is my constructor & class definition:

```
class NVPost
{
public $id;
public $county;
public $M_A1;
public $M_A2;

function __construct($inId=null, $inCounty=null, $inM_A1=null, $inM_A2=null)
{
if (!empty($inId))
{
    $this->id = $inId;
}
if (!empty($inCounty))
{
    $this->county = $inCounty;
}
if (!empty($inM_A1))
{
    $this->m_a1 = $inM_A1;
}
if (!empty($inM_A2))
{
    $this->m_a2 = $inM_A2;
}
}
}
```

Here is my displaytable.php:

```
foreach ($nvPosts as $post)
{
    echo"<TR>";
        echo"<TD>" . $post->county . "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>" . $post->m_a1 . "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>" . $post->m_a2 . "</TD>";
    echo"</TR><br>";
}
```

The problem is that it throws this error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: NVPost::$m_a1 in C:\...\votenight\displaynvtable.php on line 34
```

when I have it as m_a1 and m_a2 but those go away when I do M_A1 and M_A2 but then it only displays the county information.
I have followed the same style on a similar problem but there I only have only MySQL table but it gives me no errors.

Can someone please help me?

EDITS:

```
function GetNVPosts ($inID=null)
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT table1.id, table1.county, table1.M_A as 'M_A1', table2.M_A as 'M_A2' FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.county = table2.county");
$postArray = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $myPost = new NVPost($row["id"], $row['county'], $row['M_A1'], $row['M_A2']);
            array_push($postArray, $myPost);
}
return $postArray;
echo $postArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't have two columns with the same name on SQL, use aliases

```
... table1.M_A as M_A1, table2.M_A as M_A2 ...
```

then the final names of the columns on the result are the aliases, so you have `$row['M_A1']` and `$row['M_A2']`

Comment: Where should I make that change?

Comment: in your query the first part, and in the `new NVPOST()` parameters the second

Comment: I did that but now I'm only halfway there:  I get this error
Undefined property: NVPost::$m_a2 in C:\...\displaynvtable.php on line 35

but it does is fine for m_a1

Comment: your properties are defined in the class header in uppercase, but you are assigning them in lowercase, perhaps that's the problem. can you repost your code as it is now?